# How spark works in terms of Persisting, Spilling To Disk, Partitioning ? Is Spark not a Better option always compared to HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 2.1.0.

What is the Difference between Spark Spilling on Disk and Persist/Caching. I mean how they work.
Spilling to Disk means when a task is working on some partition & that is too big to fit into the memory, It spills to Disk. Is this Correct?

Persist/Caching is when we have done some computation on a RDD or filtered out some data and we want the Resultant RDD  to be stored to Re-use it so we persist it. This will avoid all the re-compuation from the 1st Step.

The reason i want to get these terms/definitions get cleared is to know that whether Spark along with its SQL module(SparkSQL) can be Complete Replacement 
of HIVE .. ???

And the reason made me to Ask this is I am running a Spark Job and as an Exercise i have to run all the Existing Jobs (queries) into Spark.
As this is a very straight-forward and transparent activity because Spark runs Queries very well & with same accuracy with the help of spark-hive library jar.

During this multiple questions arised for the way Spark works & its ability to deal with Huge Datasets.

Ok to start with HIVE - It works on a partition and writes intermediate/temp data on Disk and keeps moving ahead. I don't know whether HIVE/MR calls this mechanism as Spilling because to compute anything it has to be loaded in memory period(Spark or HIVE). Now as the Disk writing is involved it is Slow But less prone to Failure because of memory issues Here the Container size won't matter much i guess due to its default nature of working to write to temp files on disk.

Coming on to Spark - With all its fame of doing loading data/partitions into Memory and computing in Memory with DAG preparation...Is the difference only with the Size/amount of data loaded in memory for Computation and Temporary computed data storage as **Compared to HIVE where it writes to Disk for everything...?? Or Does it actually have something more..???**

Comment: That's a lot of different question (most of which, have already answers here). I'd suggest limiting the scope and / or separating this into multiple questions.

Comment: Yes it has to be because if you read Everything is related. Even if split the question i need to provide Background. Here i have given the entire background so that people can provide the link for reading if i misunderstood concepts, some pointers from the problem scenario's point of view

Comment: @ user8371915 -> Hope now i have limited the scope ..?

Comment: Can Anybody please answer this ..??